# django-avatar, 1 query per avatar loaded

Tags: sql, django, django-select-related

I'm displaying a page with around 60 avatars using django-avatar and a query is made for each one of them.

I cannot use `User.objects.select_related('avatar')` because there is no link between my user and his avatar. So how do I optimize this?

**EDIT**:

Avatars are retrieved in the template using {% avatar user %} (this is a template tag specific to github.com/jezdez/django-avatar, which seems to be the most used application for handling user avatars. I'm asking this question because some people certainly already had to face the issue of displaying many avatars using this application and I would like to know their solution).

Comment: What do you mean by no link between a user and his avatar?

Comment: I don't have a link user -> avatar. But I have a link avatar -> user. This is actually a question very specific to django-avatar (https://github.com/jezdez/django-avatar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the cache (like memcached) is the answer.